# Matlab remove loop to calculate PT1

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am calculating PT1 behavior in Matlab using the input vector u:

```
u(20:50,1) = 2;
k = 0.8;
x=zeros(50,1);
for i=2:size(u,1)
    x(i) = k*x(i-1) + (1-k)*u(i);
end
```

How can I remove the for loop to get the same result?

Comment: there is a relation to previous values of x in the calculation of x(i), so you can only remove the loop if you remove this relation and explicite x(i)

Comment: I thought using cumsum or something similar might help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a first-order IIR filter, so you can use [`filter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/filter.html) for that:

```
u(20:50, 1) = 2;
k = 0.8;
x = filter(1 - k, [1, -k], u);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write x(i) out for a couple of values, you'll see a pattern in it:

```
x(1) = 0; % since the loop starts at i=2
x(2) = k*x(1) + (1-k)*u(2)
     = 0      + (1-k)*u(2)
x(3) = k*x(2) + (1-k)*u(3)
     = k*(1-k)*u(2) + (1-k)*u(3)
x(4) = k*x(3) + (1-k)*u(4)
     = k^2*(1-k)*u(2) + k*(1-k)*u(3) + (1-k)*u(4)
...
```

So you'll easily spot the pattern being:

```
x(i) = (1-k) * sum(k^(i-j)*u(j), j=2..i)
```

which is now an explicit function.

You could apply this to remove your loop, but in reality this explicit function itself must calculate a large sum. Doing this for every index of x takes probably more time than looping and re-using prior results.

Comment: I don't think that this is slower than a `for` loop, but clearly [convolution](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/conv.html) would a better approach than this.

Comment: @EitanT I'm still thinking of a way to simply write this with a couple of vectorized operations, but can't immediately come up with one; hence the remark about speed. A direct application of an existing filter is indeed more appropriate.

Comment: There is no need for workarounds, since this sum is the very definition of [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution) :)

Comment: of course, but I was thinking about it just as a brain teaser/exercise